# k-nearest neaighbors search from delaunay triangulation in MATLAB (or general algorithm)

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor, delaunay

I know I can use a data structure such as the kd-tree to look for the k nearest points to each point in the plane (using the Euclidean distance).  But I've already constructed a Delaunay triagulation in my program, so I'd like to find the k nearest neighbors more efficiently by taking adavntage of the Delaunay triangulation.  I'm using Matlab, and the delaunayTriangulation class allows to query only the first nearest neighbor to a given point.  How can I find the k nearest neighbors in MATLAB using the Delaunay triangulation?  Or otherwise, if I have to implement myself the k nearest neighbors search algorithm from the Delaunay triangulation, can you point me out to such an algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only interested in finding k points nearest to a centroid, then forget you have triangles. You have a cloud of points (that cloud be related to triangles, but its irrelevant) that you need to find kn nearest neighbors to it.

[`knnsearch()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) is sufficient.

---

**Original answer:**

When I had this problem, I found 2 efficient solutions.

1. if you want K nearest neighbours to an arbitrary point, you need to build a tree. I used R*-trees because they allow volumetric objects, but if you only consider the centroid of the elements then you can survive with an easier to code tree.
2. If you want K nearest neighbors to an element itself, the best way I found is by building a network graph. A Delaunay triangulation is not structure and finding in this list gets intractable soon as you increase it, so you need to enforce some order. You need to build a graph that will order these elements and store their neighbours, so you can simply query neigbours in distance from the element if your interest.

I found no MATLAB function to solve this for me and [I ended up writing my own stuff](https://github.com/AnderBiguri/TriangleCT). This was in a larger framework of using tetrahedra as image basis for computed tomography, so there is a lot of extra stuff in that repo and things may need touching here and there. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll look at it.  Actually I only need to find k nearest points to circumcenters of the triangles (so at least three nearest points).  With this specification, do you think there is maybe  an easier solution?

Comment: If I have a circumcentre c and I need to find k>3 points, I could take the bordering triangles to the central triangle and take the closest k points to the centre among the vertices of those triangles if I gor at least k vertices; otherwise I keep adding another layer of border until I have at least k vertices.  But I don't know if this idea guarantees me to find the nearest points.  What do you think?

Comment: @Matteo if you only need to find the k nearest points to a circumcenter, then forget that you have triangles. You just have a bunch of points (that have some relation to triangles, but are irrelevant). So its just your standard Knn stuff. Also have a look at Voronoi meshes, they are the dual-mesh to delaunay and link the circumcenters together